# Siri shortcuts do not disturb bug?

Tags: sirishortcuts

I have been trying to write a shortcut to work as a pomodoro timer. Basically, I would like it to set a timer for 25 minutes, then put my phone on DND for 25 minutes. I have been trying to do this second part with a DND “until” and a magic variable holding a date +25 minutes, but the DND is never turning off.

I have tried turning off my DND schedule on my phone, but that has not helped. I’ve attached the (simple) shortcut below.

https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/856239d511ca4e5fb0d204fbf6bcd78f